# What good is a cofibration of categories?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

I'm working on a problem where I have a cofibration of $V$-enriched categories $f: A\to B$, and would like to study the induced functor on presheaves $[B,V] \to [A,V]$. We can assume $V$ is a combinatorial, simplicial, monoidal model category, and satisfies pretty much whatever model category properties you want. By a cofibration of $V$-categories we mean a cofibration in the [Berger-Moerdijk model structure](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.2134). We can also assume $[B,V]$ and $[A,V]$ have projective model structures. If you don't like enriched categories, I'm also happy with the unenriched case, just to have some new ideas (so, a cofibration then is in the [folk model structure](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/canonical+model+structure+on+Cat), i.e. injective on objects).

My collaborator and I have been trying to prove that, for $X$ and $Y$ bifibrant in $B$, then the morphism of simplicial mapping spaces $Map_{[B,V]}(X,Y) \to Map_{[A,V]}(f^* X, f^* Y)$ is a fibration.

> (1) Is this true?

In general, I don't really know how to use the hypothesis, i.e. I don't know what $f$ being a cofibration buys me, from the point of view of presheaves $[B,V]\to [A,V]$.

> (2) Is anything known about the collection of functors between presheaf categories induced by cofibrations?

Thanks!

Comment: Re (2): A.3.3.9 of Higher Topos Theory shows that if $f$ is a cofibration then $f^*$ preserves projective cofibrations and that $F \to f^* f_! F$ is a projective cofibration for projectively cofibrant $F$.

Comment: @JohnDougherty - thanks for the reference! I will see if I can make it work to complete the proof I'm working on!

Comment: @JohnDougherty: thanks, that turned out to be just what I needed to finish the proof. Once I've got the paper written, maybe I'll come back and answer my own question here explaining what I did.